# SQL SELECT alternating rows based on dept id and date added

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to select the most recent record for each dept, then the 2nd most recent, then the 3rd, etc.  Each department can have any number of records with varying dates, so there is no correlation. I'm using SQL Server.

```
TABLE PROD (
   PRODNAME VARCHAR(50),
   DEPTID INT,
   ADDED DATEIME
)
```

I need the results to look like this:

```
PRODNAME    DEPTID  ADDED
------------------------------
Q           1       2014-08-05 <-- DEPT 1, 1ST MOST RECENT
X           2       2014-08-05 <-- DEPT 2, 1ST MOST RECENT
W           3       2013-05-23 <-- DEPT 3, 1ST MOST RECENT
P           1       2014-07-12 <-- DEPT 1, 2ND MOST RECENT
A           2       2013-09-10 <-- DEPT 2, 2ND MOST RECENT
K           3       2013-01-12 <-- DEPT 3, 2ND MOST RECENT
L           1       2014-07-05 <-- DEPT 1, 3RD MOST RECENT
(NO MORE DEPT 2 RECORDS AVAILABLE, SO GO TO NEXT DEPT)
G           3       2012-12-18 <-- DEPT 3, 3RD MOST RECENT
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with the `ROW_NUMBER()` function:

```
;WITH cte AS (SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY DeptID ORDER BY Added DESC) RN
              FROM Table1)
SELECT Prodname, DeptID, Added
FROM cte
ORDER BY RN, DeptID
```

Demo: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5fe45/1/0)

The `ROW_NUMBER()` function assigns a number to each row. `PARTITION BY` is optional, but used to start the numbering over for each value in that group,  ie: if you `PARTITION BY DeptID`  then for each unique `DeptID` value the numbering would start over at 1.  `ORDER BY` of course is used to define how the counting should go, and is required in the `ROW_NUMBER()` function.

If you `SELECT *` in the query above you can get a sense for how the `ROW_NUMBER()` function works.

Edit: Updated SQL Fiddle with example of missing deptid